# Undefined symbol error when creating postgis extension

Tags: postgis, extensions

When trying to create `postgis` extension, I'm getting an error, no references in google on it.

```
maptest=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/pgsql-9.3/lib/rtpostgis-2.1.so": /usr/pgsql-9.3/lib/rtpostgis-2.1.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK11xercesc_3_013XMLAttDefList14isSerializableEv
```

- RHEL 6 64bit
- PostgreSQL 9.3.5
- GDAL 1.11.0
- postgis-2.1.0

Any ideas?

UPD.also, after some looking around:

```
[root@ror6ax3 ~]# ldd -d /usr/pgsql-9.3/lib/rtpostgis-2.1.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffd3bff000)
        libgeos_c.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libgeos_c.so.1 (0x00007f5275679000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f5275463000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f52751de000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f5274fc8000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5274c34000)
        libgeos-3.3.2.so => /usr/lib64/libgeos-3.3.2.so (0x00007f52748a2000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f527459c000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5276381000)
undefined symbol: _ZNK11xercesc_3_013XMLAttDefList14isSerializableEv    (/usr/pgsql-9.3/lib/rtpostgis-2.1.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN11xercesc_3_013XMLAttDefList9serializeERNS_16XSerializeEngineE     (/usr/pgsql-9.3/lib/r                                                                                                                                tpostgis-2.1.so)
undefined symbol: _ZNK11xercesc_3_013XMLAttDefList12getProtoTypeEv      (/usr/pgsql-9.3/lib/rtpostgis-2.1.so)
undefined symbol: H5T_NATIVE_SHORT_g    (/usr/pgsql-9.3/lib/rtpostgis-2.1.so)
```

The behavior is same when building another versions from sources.

Comment: What Operating System and Version are you using and how did you install PostGis

Comment: RHEL 6 64bit. I did build it from source